# a house of ghosts

Tags: meaning, possessives, attributives

a. People used to think that that lone house on the hill was a house of ghosts.

I don't think 'of' here indicates ownership. I think it is just attributive and shows that the house was haunted. Is that correct?

---

b. The problem of inflation is not just a problem of politicians.

In (b), does 'of' indicate possession. I don't think so. I think the idea is that the problem doesn't merely consist of what politicians do.

Comment: (a) Yes. (b) I would expect 'a problem _for_ politicians'.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you're right, but, being generous, there is a natural reading with "of politicians" like: "The problem of inflation is not just a problem caused by politicians". It's unclear at best

Answer (score 2):

The preposition 'of' has many uses. You will find these listed in a good dictionary along with comparable examples.

> a house of ghosts

It could be argued that 'of' here means *containing* - like a 'bag of apples', or a 'hall of mirrors' - as the house contains ghosts. It could also mean *comprising or consisting of* in a figurative way - for example, 'a book of memories' doesn't literally contain memories but may contain photographs or writing that invokes memories for certain people.

> a problem of politicians

I see this as definitely meaning ownership. The context is saying that it is a problem *not just* belonging to politicians, but to everyone, potentially. The way you have understood it would not be expressed that way. We would say that a problem had been *caused by* them.